# USB claimInterface return false

Tags: android, methods, usb

When I used claimInterface method on the USB serial device at android,
always returned false.
Do I have to specify "true" in claimInterface second argument?
Could I teach me why?

device: android 5

Comment: Depends on the interface. Some interface types are used by the system automagically, especially HID.

Comment: thanks, In android app, should I specify "true" in claimInterface second argument?